# Replication Issue with computed columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-replication

So the situation is there are two servers `pub_server`(publisher) and `sub_server` (subscriber).
There are two databases on pub_server : `db1` and `db2`.

There exists a table `xyz_tbl` in db1 which is replicated(transactional) to the `sub_server` (publisher name : `publisher_old`).
My task is to drop the subscription and article from `publisher_old` and create a new publisher `publisher_new` at db2 with same article `xyz_tbl` and same subscriber `sub_server`.

Now here is the problem : the `xyz_tbl` has a computed column. So when I executed the script for `publisher_new` I get error in Replication Monitor.

Error : `The column "column_name" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator`

I am using `@sync_type="replication support only"` since table already exists at subscriber (from `publisher_old`). Then why distributor is trying to perform insertion on subscriber which generates above error.

If at all distributor is trying insertion then how come the replication was working from `db1` i.e `publisher_old`.

How to handle computed columns in replication. I couldn't find any answer.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the works are not available for computed columns.Such is updating.
I recommend not to replicate computed column. You can compute it again in your replication db.

Other way is make computed column an actual column, and then replicate.

If you want insert to computed column, then you can make kind property be equal to PersistantReadOnly.

Comment: How we can set PersistantReadOnly property?

Answer (score 0):

But if calculated column persisted  in replication is not replicarted as definition replication of other object fail and if add it should be removed before bcp. and at the end you can add them on subscriber only through creating on publisher (dop and recreate) and replicating bit then you can have problem with FK and indexes.